# Windows Phone : Animating an image from Point A to B using PointAnimation

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to programmatically achieve translating an image from Point A to to the center of the screen on Windows Phone. I've tried many different approaches, and this is the code for my latest approach (it doesn't work) :

```
        var trans = new TranslateTransform() {
            X = 1.0,
            Y = 1.0
        };
        img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        img.RenderTransform = trans;

        var moveAnim = new PointAnimation();
        moveAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        moveAnim.From = new Point((double)originalPosition[0],(double)originalPosition[1]);
        moveAnim.To = new Point(centerX, centerY);


        Storyboard.SetTarget(moveAnim, img);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveAnim, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));

        storyboard.Children.Add(moveAnim);
        storyboard.Begin();
```

I'm completely confused about what to use as the TargetProperty for a PointAnimation! I've used TranslateTransform.X or Y when working with a Double Animation. I know I can use 2 DoubleAnimations and achieve this, but I'd like to know how I can get PointAnimation to work. 
Thanks.

Comment: you want the animation made necessarily in cs or xaml will also do?

Comment: Necessarily in cs, the image is added in dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I make an animation in cs
make a global storyboard object

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
```

and then make the story board like this.

```
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2));

            // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
            DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
            DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

            myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
            myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

            sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Duration = duration;

            sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
            sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, image);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, image);
            PropertyPath p1=new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");
             PropertyPath p2=new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
            // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
            // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations
             Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, p1);
             Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, p2);

            myDoubleAnimation1.To = 0;
            myDoubleAnimation2.To = 200;
            LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("ab", sb);
```

finally the code to start an animation

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sb.Begin();
        }
```

Changes to be done on the image

```
image=new Image();
CompositeTransform ct=new CompositeTransform ();
image.RenderTransform=ct;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aman, but I need to do it via code, as I add in the image on a Canvas at runtime.

Comment: This works great! I found an example using 2 DoubleAnimations on the Microsoft site too. But is there no way to achieve this using PointAnimations? It seems like a hack to use 2 separate animations on X and Y to achieve something. Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Name = "img";
img.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

Storyboard moveSb = new Storyboard();
TranslateTransform moveTransform = new TranslateTransform();
img.RenderTransform = moveTransform;
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimationX.Duration = duration;
myDoubleAnimationX.To = 200;
moveSb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationX);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimationX, moveTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationX, "X");
moveSb.Begin();
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks